# Logcat error and app keeps crashing with android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException?

Tags: javascript, java, android, sdk

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what to do anymore, please, can you help?

**Logcat logs**

```
  Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@17b6660 -- permission denied for window type 2002
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:931)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:387)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
            at com.example.littlezero2.Shimeji.ShimejiView (Shimeji.java:182)
            at com.example.littlezero2.Shimeji.pause (Shimeji.java:111)
            at com.example.littlezero2.Shimeji.onCreate (Shimeji.java:95)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:219) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

> Okay, so this is a snippet of where the crash is happening I hope this
> helps. I'm not getting any errors in the build and I have already run
> it through the debugger, I've changed the phone part to WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY but still the same error occurs from Logcat. I have traced the error from the three lines given in the logcat.

```
Line 182  wm.addView ( view, params );
Line 111  ShimejiView ();
Line 95 pause ();
```

I have an error?

> The code where it's coming from.
>
> Java

```
@Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }
        private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    
        public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            Shimeji getService() {
                return Shimeji.this;
            }
        }
    
    
        /** end of binder */
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Notification();
            pause();
        }
    
    
    
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            wm.removeViewImmediate(view);
            nm.cancel(001200);
            if (!isMuted){
                stopsound();
            }
            timing.cancel();
            running.cancel();
        }
    
        protected void pause(){
            if (isPaused) {
                ShimejiView();
                randomsens();
                handler.post(draw());
                sp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.start);
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poi);
                bp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.baka);
                sp.start();
                isPaused = false;
                view.setOnTouchListener(new action());
    
                builder.setContentText("Poi is running");
                nm.notify(
                        01200,
                        builder.build());
            } else if(!isPaused){
                wm.removeViewImmediate(view);
                if (!isMuted){
                    stopsound();
                }
                timing.cancel();
                running.cancel();
                isPaused = true;
                builder.setContentText("Poi is paused");
                nm.notify(
                        01200,
                        builder.build());
            }
        }
    
    
        private class action implements View.OnTouchListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        idleanimation.stop();
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blink1);
                        blinkanimation = (AnimationDrawable)view.getBackground();
                        blinkanimation.start();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                        params.x= (x_cord-(width/2));
                        params.y =(y_cord-(height/2)-50);
                        wm.updateViewLayout(view, params);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        touchcheck();
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.idle1);
                        idleanimation = (AnimationDrawable)view.getBackground();
                        idleanimation.start();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        private void ShimejiView()
        {
            view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.idle1);
            idleanimation = (AnimationDrawable)view.getBackground();
            idleanimation.start();
            view.setOnTouchListener(new action());
            li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
            myview = li.inflate(R.layout.playground, null);
            wm.addView(view,params);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
```

You're using it in your ShimejiView method.

"This constant was deprecated in API level 26. for non-system apps. Use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead."

Found in the documentation:
See here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams

Maybe that is your issue?

It matches the trace, if I had to put money on it that would be it.  You should check out the Window Manager documentation if that's not it and maybe you'll find something else.